# How can I create PDF output from rrdcgi?

Tags: html, perl, rrdtool

I have created a [rrdcgi](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcgi.en.html) script to display information about the system performance with graphs. Now I would like to add an option for the users to create PDF on the fly with the details on current page (images and information) and header and footer. I also want the generated PDF files to be saved in some location so that that can be easily accessed next time. Is this possible to do with [rrdcgi](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcgi.en.html) or any Perl code would be really appreciated.

I need this options

Comment: It doesn't have Perl bindings, but I just read yesterday about a new service that allows for easy conversion of HTML to PDF. At the moment, it's in beta, but it might be worth a look: https://pdfcrowd.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider what you want to put in the PDF: Do you want an exact replica of the web page the user is viewing (too hard to be close to impossible without having the user's browser installed on your side and using its print output) or do you want the same information in a roughly similar layout?

An important issue is how you are generating the HTML: I did something similar once to generate PDF receipts for experiment participants (now, I just [output HTML with print styles](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/03/html-layouts-for-print.html)).

The HTML is generated using [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template) although [Template.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template) would be just as fine.

It is then trivial to write another template, one that generates a [L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X](http://www.latex-project.org/) document which can be processed using [pdflatex](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/). If you save the data the time the snapshot is requested, you can add the snapshot to a queue that generates documents asynchronously so that requests do not tie up the web server.

**Update:** Looking at [rrdcgi](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdcgi.en.html), I now realize that it already does use a template. That is perfect: Instead of putting HTML in the template, put [L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X](http://www.latex-project.org/) code in the template and run `rrdcgi` with the `--filter` option to create a L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X source file which you can run through `pdflatex`. I guess the problem to solve there is to be able to use the exact same data that was used to generate the page the user is looking at.

If it is not possible to re-run `rrdcgi` with the exact same data, consider adding some JavaScript that submits the HTML source of the page the user is reviewing (or some JSON representation thereof) to a CGI script that parses the HTML and outputs L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X. Writing clean HTML in the original template and judicious use of `class` and `id` attributes would help there.

I do not have time to test any of these ideas right now, but I will take a look again within the next couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Is it worth the effort?

Why don't you add a FAQ explaining how to setup a PDF-printer on Windows/MAC/Linux and provide a 'clean' page that can then be printed?

---

Since you apparently have to create the PDF,

- take a look at [this (what-is-the-best-perl-module-to-use-for-creating-a-pdf-from-scratch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556786/what-is-the-best-perl-module-to-use-for-creating-a-pdf-from-scratch) post here on SO.
- There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120155/how-can-i-convert-html-to-pdf-using-perl) post, that could combine the 'clean' HTML page and a server-side print.

Comment: Thanks Lexu: This is the good option but not work for me. I also want to save the auto generated pdf files to save in some defined path on file system and can be accessed easily next time.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the LaTeX route, if you have rrdcgi generate graphs in pdf format, pdflatex will be able to integrate them directly into the document, producing super quality pdf with graphs ... very slick. Sorry, no code.